# Swift -how is a collectionView's scrollView.content.y determined?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have a collectionView with 5 cells. After I drag the collectionView down using this scrollView method I can get the following:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y // 92 ???
    print("currentOffset: \(currentOffset)")

    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height // height of all the cells added together -616.310
    print("contentHeight: \(contentHeight)")

    let frame = scrollView.frame.size.height // height of the collectionView itself from it's topAnchor to it's bottomAnchor - 725
    print("frame: \(frame)")

    let maximumOffset = contentHeight - frame // -108.689453125 // distance between contentHeight (bottom of all the cells) and the frame
    print("maximumOffset: \(maximumOffset)")
}
```

The `contentHeight` is the height of all the cells added together which is: `-616.310`

The `frame` is the height of the collectionView itself in between it's topAnchor and it's bottomAnchor which is: `725`

The `maximumOffset` is the distance between contentHeight (bottom of all the cells) and the frame which is: `-108.689453125`

What I can't figure out is where does the `currentOffset` which is `92` comes from.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset) isn't very clear:

> **contentOffset**
>
> The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the
>   origin of the scroll view.

**After dragging the collectionView, how is the currentOffset determined?**

In the picture below at the bottom is the debugger with the print statements from the `scrollViewDidEndDragging` method

[image]

Not sure if this makes any difference or not but the collectionView's topAnchor and bottomAnchor are pinned to the view's `safeAreaLayoutGuide ..., constant: 0` or it's anchored directly to it's top and bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's how far the scrollView's top left hand corner (0,0) is from the top of the collectionView's top left hand corner (0,0) after the the collectionView is first dragged and let go.

So it was initially pulled up 92 points (0,-92) then let go.